# (Unity) How can I programmatically make Array Elements Clickable?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, element, gameobject

I have Array Elements  I got them on an Empty GameObject, I mean [SerializeField] and added through the script (C# Ofcourse), So the Objects are not really there they are being Generated when the Game begins. How can I clone the Collider from the Empty GameObject onto the clones in order to make them clickable? So far as of right now only the first one works witch is also the possition of the empty GameObject who has the colider on it now I need them onto the Clones as well... but,...How?

I tried to apply the collider to the sprites I even tried turning them into Prefab Its All hopeless. I do think It has to be on the script but I cannot find a code example of it....

```
public class Controll : MonoBehaviour {
public const int gridRows = 6;
public const int gridCols = 6;
public const float offsetX = 1.70f;
public const float offsetY = 0.97f;

[SerializeField] private GameObject[] cardBack;
[SerializeField] private GameObject[] positioner;

public AudioSource sound;

public void OnMouseDown()
{

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        sound.Play();
    }
}

//AudioSource audioSource;



// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{
   // audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();

    Vector3 startPos = positioner[0].transform.position;
    for (int i = 0; i < gridRows; i++)

    {
        for (int j = 0; j < gridCols; j++)
        {

            var position = transform.position + new Vector3(offsetX * j, offsetY * i * -1, -0.1f);
            Instantiate(cardBack[i], position, Quaternion.identity, transform);
        }
   }
}
```

I need to be able to click on these elements so they be playing a sound when i click and disappear....

Comment: How?
I mentioned that I tried that and it was hopeless....
If.... I'm not getting any Code-samples then I wouldn't know how.....

Comment: set the prefab up with all the things, colliders, scripts etc, then it goes with the collider.  There isnt enough here for anyone to tell you whats wrong, and SO isnt here to write a step by step how to for you.

Comment: That is not something witch would work.

1.) I tried it a long time ago

2.) there are clones witch are only there during play mode runs otherwise it won't exist

3.)@BugFinder It doesn't matter how many are around to help, it matters that almost everybody has more experience as I do and there must be someone who has the Answer to this............since every experienced Unity user has had to deal with this

Comment: well.. scripts and colliders can and do frequently get setup on prefabs.. you can add components at run time, but of course you've read on that and tried it.. But if it works for 1 item and not the rest, then you need to work out why not.. the array specifically shouldnt matter its the actual gameobjects that do

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution...

@ BugFinder
I had cut out the function "on mouse down" and pasted it onto a separated script with just that function and applied that to all the prefabs while the other script with all other functions has stayed on the game-object. So that seems to work well so far.....